# No User exists for 'query user'

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, windows-command-prompt

I have one weird issue on the virtual machine. When I do 'query user user1' is not showing the active session of the user. It says 'No User exists for user1', though there is active connection. However it works fine for other users.  Why is this happening? Please help. Thanks.

```
C:\Users\user2>query user
 USERNAME         SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 user2            rdp-tcp#2           2  Active          .  4-1-2022 12:12
>user1            rdp-tcp#57          3  Active          .  4-1-2022 13:35

C:\Users\user2>query user user1
No User exists for user1

C:\Users\user2>query user user2
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 user2         rdp-tcp#57          3  Active          .  4-1-2022 13:35
```

Comment: What happens when you type "query session rdp-tcp#57", replacing "rdp-tcp#57" with whatever that user's current session name is?

Comment: Are you an administrator on that VM?